# BOOST_concept redefined warning when using boost graph library

Tags: xcode, boost

I'm building a project on XCode 3.2.6 gcc 4.2 which uses the boost graph library (1.45).  The build results in an annoying warning:

```
/include/boost/concept/detail/concept_def.hpp:34:1: warning: "BOOST_concept" redefined
```

concept_def.hpp does not appear to contain any protection to prevent this sort of multiple definition and the boost graph library seems to be constructed so as to ensure it is included multiple times. In my case the include sequences are:

One definition:

```
/include/boost/concept/detail/concept_def.hpp:34
/include/boost/graph/buffer_concepts.hpp:9,
/include/boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp:21,
/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:31,
```

Another definition:

```
/include/boost/concept/detail/concept_def.hpp:34
/include/boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp:25,
/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:31,
```

While this is only a warning I find it hard to believe this was released with boost and hence expect I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Barrie

Answer (score 1):

Error only seems to happen on XCode, all of our other platforms (linux gcc4, msvc2010) build fine.

Here is our workaround:

boost/concept/detail/concept_def.hpp:12

```
#ifdef BOOST_concept
# undef BOOST_concept
#endif
```

PS:
 In case you are wondering why we don't put an #ifndef guard around the whole file then know that for some strange reason this does not work!

Answer (score 0):

The issue posted in the page is the same one we encountered. Following is our solution based on the concention

> add #include  in the end of a hpp file  if  is included in the beginning of the file.

we added the include concept_undef.hpp in the end of **buffer_concepts.hpp** accordingly and it does solve the compiling error.